# Controlling dependencies in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using Laravel-mix and Webpack to combine and control scripts for a site.

I'm my main `app.js` I have these lines:

```
var jQuery = require( 'jquery' );
require( './vendor/polyfill-library.min.js' );
require( './vendor/polyfill-init.js' ); // which is using jQuery
```

In `polyfill-init.js` I'm doing this: `jQuery( document ).ready( ...`. That results in this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

I also get this error if I try and mix it together using Laravel-mix, by adding this to my webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.js( [
    'resources/js/app.js',
    'resources/js/vendor/polyfill-library.min.js',
    'resources/js/vendor/polyfill-init.js',
  ], 'assets/js/app.js')
```

I assume the error is because Webpack keeps the required/imported scripts in seperate namespaces/environments, so no conflicts occur. And that's all fine and dandy, - but I don't know how to combine two required/imported scripts, so they're using the same namespace/environment.

... If I copy all the code into `app.js` (instead of requiring it), then it works, but it's not pretty. Not pretty at all.

I looked at [Webpack's documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/) to see if there's a way to define a dependency for an imported/a required script, but either it's not there; or I'm not getting it.

I also looked at the [7 billion ways that this post suggest that I'd do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/1766219), - but I'm trying to figure out how Webpack/Laravel-mix want me to do it.

---

So my question is... Are there a way that I can do something like this:

```
var jQuery = require( 'jquery' );
require( './vendor/polyfill-library.min.js' );
require( './vendor/polyfill-init.js' ); // which is using jQuery
```

... and let Webpack know, that `polyfill-init` can use `jQuery`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try window.jQuery = require( 'jquery' );

polyfill-init.js probably looks for jQuery in global scope while the var jQuery is only available in the local scope of this module.

Answer (score 4):

You can use provideplugin:

```
 plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        })
    ]
```

Comment: That is in the webpack-config-file, - where I would like to control it all in the `webpack.mix.js`-file, so I can have the default settings, as far as possible.

Answer (score 0):

U should externalize JQuery from the webpack.

index.html

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery'
  }
};
```

polyfill-init.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Refer more details here https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/